# Conjugating into なければ

Tags: conjugations

To create ～なければいけません or similar forms, I've been having trouble finding the exact method for conjugating into ～なければ.

I imagine (but also greatly doubt) that it's something like this: 食べる -> 食べない -> 食べなく -> 食べなける -> 食べければ. However, even if it was like that I still wouldn't really understand why. Can anyone explain the exact process to get from ～ない to ～なければ?

Answer (score 9):

### A modern perspective

`〜ければ` is the conditional ending for adjectives.  Since the `〜ない` form of verbs is shaped like an adjective, it uses adjective endings like `〜い` and `〜ければ`.  That's it!  From a modern perspective, there are no steps in-between.

However, some grammars do take it one step further: they divide `〜ければ` into `〜けれ` (the hypothetical form of an adjective), plus `ば` (a conditional particle).  This explanation is attractive because `ば` appears elsewhere with conditional meaning, as in `ならば`.

But either way, it's pretty simple.  `〜なければ` is the negative conditional form.

---

### A historical perspective

Historically speaking, `〜ければ` was presumably formed by a contraction of some sort.  But what sort?  The explanation @istrasci gives is a common one and can be found elsewhere on this site, that`〜ければ` was a contraction of `〜く+あれば`.  In turn, we can say `あれば` was a form of `ある` with the conditional `〜ば` attached.<sup>†</sup>

However, this leaves us wondering why the first vowel is /e/ rather than /a/.  Sansom, on page 205 of his 1928 [*Historical Grammar of Japanese*](https://archive.org/stream/historicalgramma00sansuoft#page/205/mode/2up), gives an explanation:

> This change is easy to understand, for the final *e* of *kare* influences the preceding vowel *a*, by a tendency which is common in Japanese.

In contrast, Frellesvig, in his 2010 *History of the Japanese Language*, suggests that the `〜けれ` stem comes from a contraction of **ki-are* into *kyere*, giving way to modern *kere*.  Either way, it's a contraction of  some sort of adjectival form plus `あれば`.

---

### What is ある doing there?

The presence of `ある` is most likely purely grammatical, inserted so that endings like `〜ば` can attach to adjectives.  We shouldn't really translate it as "exists" in English.  Instead, we should describe `〜なければ` as the conditional form of the negative `〜ない`.

This sort of grammatical use of `ある` is common and can be seen in all sorts of places in Japanese, including in other adjectival inflections:

> 〜な**く**＋**あ**った　＞　〜な**か**った

I trust you understand that `〜なかった` is simply a negative past form, and that you don't attempt to translate it as though it has "exists" in it.  You can apply the same sort of logic here.

---

### Historical versus modern

Why look at it from a modern perspective?  Well, let me ask you this: when you say ***goodbye*** in English, do you always think [***God be with ye***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=goodbye&searchmode=none)?  Of course not!  Historically speaking, it's a contraction of that phrase, but today speakers use ***goodbye*** as a pre-formed unit.  It's simply part of their vocabulary.  In that sense, the word is no longer a contraction.

Likewise, when you say `〜なければ`, please don't think something like "if it's such that you don't", as @istrasci wrote.  It's simply a negative conditional form.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup>*For simplicity's sake, I'm referring to this verb as* ある, *which is its modern citation form.  Its historical citation form was* あり.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

`〜なければ` is a contraction of `〜なく＋あれば`.  Of course the `〜ば` form is a conditional and `〜なく` is the "adverbial" form of a negation.  So you can kind of translate it as "If it is/exists such that 〜 doesn't happen".

> 食べなければ`　→　If it's such that you don't eat　→　If you don't eat

---

Related:  [Origin of ~なければ ならない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11788/78)