# Meaning of てはならない

Tags: grammar

```
ただしい じょうほう にもとづいて はっぴょう しなくてはならない
```

I understand that `てはならない` means 'must not/should not'.
However,I cannot make any sense out of the above sentence that I read in a book.
Would appreciate if someone could assist with the meaning.

Comment: What part don't you understand? It seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: しなくてはならない = しない + てはならない?Is that what it means?What would this double negative translate to?

Comment: Well, try looking at the meaning of the rest of the sentence. There's no special trickery here. You should try including this kind of information (i.e. the sentence as you understand it) in the question itself.

Comment: Related [Must do : ～なければならない vs ～なくてはいけない](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2500/must-do-～なければならない-vs-～なくてはいけない) and also [Origin of ~なければ ならない](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11788/origin-of-なければ-ならない).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply,

> 「～～してはならない」 = "You must not ~~."
>
> 「～～しなくてはならない」 = "You must ~~."

「ただしいじょうほうにもとづいてはっぴょうしなくてはならない。」 means:

"One must make a/the presentation based on correct information."

Comment: Simple and to the point explanation.Thanks.