# 富士山に登るのは大変だったが、登らなければできない素晴らしい経験がいくつもできた。

Tags: meaning

富士山に登るのは大変だったが、登らなければできない素晴らしい経験がいくつもできた。

What does the なければできない mean and how is it different than なければならない？

From what I know なければならない means HAVE to do.

Comment: It might help... hint: The できる in 登らなければできない have the same meaning as the one in 経験がいくつもできた.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please forget ～ないといけない and ～なければならない for now. なければできない is totally different from them. なければできない is not a special construction, so you can just read it word by word. 体験をする means "to have an experience", and 体験ができる means "can have an experience".

- 登らなければできない体験 an experience you cannot have if you don't climb it

  - 登らなければ if you do not climb
  - できない体験 experience you cannot have

    - できない cannot (have)
    - 体験 an experience

> 富士山に登るのは大変だったが、《登らなければできない素晴らしい経験》がいくつもできた。
>
> Climbing Mt. Fuji was tough, but I was able to have many 《great experiences that I could not have had if I hadn't climbed it》.

Comment: For OP:  ～なければならない isn't really a special construction either.  See also [Origin of ~なければ ならない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11788/78).