# how does te form+ なる(ものか) work?

Tags: nuances

[image]
i pretty much know what it means, but i wanna know the nuance, what the person tries to actually say. what the なる here does??

Answer (score 3):

This なる is fundamentally the same なる as in ～てはならない. For details, see [Origin of ~なければ ならない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11788/5010)

ものか is a rhetorical question version of [ものだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010).

- くたばってはならない。
  I must not drop dead.
- くたばってはなるものか。 = くたばってなるものか。
  How should I drop dead?